# Issue with CBPeripheral connecting

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

CBCentralManager gets stuck when connecting to a device.

After starting to scan, it finds the  device and reaches the centralManager: didDiscover: method, then tries to connect to it, but the device stays in  connecting status for a while and then disconnects afterwards.

It's easily fixed by restarting the Bluetooth on device, but this isn't a solution. Does anyone have an idea why this happens?

Code:

```
//MARK: CBCentralManagerDelegate methods

    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        self.delegate?.centralServiceDidUpdateState(self)
        guard let centralManager = self.centralManager else { return }

        switch centralManager.state {
            case .poweredOn: self.scan()
            case .poweredOff: print("poweredOff")
            case .resetting: print("resetting")
            case .unauthorized: print("unauthorized")
            case .unknown: print("unknown")
            case .unsupported: print("unsupported")
        }
    }

    func scan() {
        self.centralManager?.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil)
        print("Scanning started")
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {

        self.delegate?.centralService(self, discover: peripheral.identifier.uuidString)
        let retrievedPeripherals = central.retrievePeripherals(withIdentifiers: [])

        for retrievedPeripheral in retrievedPeripherals {
            central.connect(retrievedPeripheral, options: nil)
        }

        if !retrievedPeripherals.contains(peripheral) {
            // And connect

            self.discoveredPeripheral = peripheral
            self.discoveredPeripheral?.delegate = self
            central.stopScan()

            central.connect(peripheral, options: nil)

            self.rssis[peripheral.identifier.uuidString] = "\(RSSI)"
            print("Connecting to peripheral \(peripheral)")
        }
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didFailToConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: Error?) {
        print("Failed to connect to \(peripheral). (\(error!.localizedDescription))")
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        print("Peripheral Connected with identifier: \(peripheral.identifier.uuidString)")
        self.discoveredPeripheral?.discoverServices(nil)
    }

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {
        print("Discover services for peripheralIdentifier: \(peripheral.identifier.uuidString)")

        if let error = error {
            print("Error discovering services: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }
        // Loop through the newly filled peripheral.services array, just in case there's more than one.
        for service in peripheral.services ?? [] {
            peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service)
        }
    }
```

Also I've that log from console:

```
2017-05-21 21:09:32.049137 MyApp[5871:2645747] [Fabric] Unable to locate application icon
2017-05-21 21:09:32.051153 MyApp[5871:2645747] [Crashlytics] Version 3.8.4 (121)
Scanning started
self.peripheralManager powered on.
Connecting to peripheral <CBPeripheral: 0x1700f9100, identifier = B5E6ACBF-307C-4C13-BB6A-09F4A92ABEC3, name = (null), state = connecting>
```

Problem is what not `centralManager: didFailToConnect`, not `centralManager: didConnect` is not called.

Maybe this issue somehow related to `null` name of peripheral?

**UPDATE #1:**

I've added

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 10.0) {
   print("Connecting to peripheral \(peripheral)")
}
```

And I get this in the console:

```
Connecting to peripheral <CBPeripheral: 0x1700f9100, identifier = B5E6ACBF-307C-4C13-BB6A-09F4A92ABEC3, name = (null), state = connecting>
```

So peripheral still exist after 10 seconds. So it's not a problem with deallocated and strong references.

Comment: You do `self.discoveredPeripheral =. peripheral` only in one case. So it may be linked to a strong/deallocated issue. When you retrieved it in `retievedPeripherals`, do you keep a reference there? Also, you don't set the delegate in that case so delegate methods won't be called for it.

Comment: Actually it should work without connecting to retievedPeripherals. In few lines below I doing 
self.discoveredPeripheral = peripheral
self.discoveredPeripheral?.delegate = self
central.connect(peripheral, options: nil)

From this point connecting is started, but it stuck in connecting state. After I restart Bluetooth it's works as well